# Position div below fixed div and to the right of another fixed div

Tags: html, css

I looked at some of the other answers for this, but none of them seem applicable because, although my fixed divs' dimensions are fixed, they're unknown until the page actually renders.

I have a fixed header div, followed by another div. The second div contains a sidebar div, and finally the content div:

```
<header>stuff</header>
<div id="wrapper">
    <nav>sidebar stuff</nav>
    <div id="content">Content</div>
</div>
```

The wrapper uses `display: flex` to put the sidebar and the content divs side by side.

My current goal is to fix the header and the sidebar when scrolling. The problem is that `position: fixed` takes the header and sidebar out of the regular flow, which makes it hard to position the content div relative to them. As a bonus, I don't know the dimensions of the header/sidebar until they render, so I can't just do `position: absolute` on the content div.

I am using React, and therefore would like to avoid manual DOM manipulation (e.g. jQuery).

Comment: Please check code. If any changes let me know.

Comment: Please post the CSS for the elements and for body.

Comment: @Ivan86 I am open to changing anything about my CSS - as long as height for the header is not specified (its height is derived from the content + padding).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the code. Hope it will help you. If any changes let me know.

```css
*{ 
    margin: 0px;
}

#sidebar {
 /*Strictly Necessary */
 position:fixed; 
 height: 100%;
 width:30%;
 margin: 0px;  

  /*Aesthetics*/
  background: lightblue; 
  border-radius: 7px;  
}


#rightSideWrapper {
 /*Strictly Necessary */
 width:70%; 
 float: right;

 /*Aesthetics*/
 background: black; 
}

header {
 /*Strictly Necessary */
 position: fixed;
 width: 70%; 
 height: 100px; /*Adjust the hight to your purposes*/
 
 /*Aesthetics*/
 background: lightSalmon;
 border-radius: 7px;
}

.ContentBox{
 margin-top: 100px; /*The height of the   header*/
 display:flex;
 flex-flow: row wrap;
} 

main, section, footer {
    /*Aesthetics*/
  background: lightgray; 
  border-radius: 7px; 
  margin: 5px; 
  padding: 20px;
}

main {
  /*Strictly Necessary */
  height: 400px;
  order: 1;
  flex: 0 1 100%; 
 
}

section {
  /*Strictly Necessary */
   height: 400px;
   order: 2;
   flex: 0 1 100%;
 
}

footer {
  /*Strictly Necessary */
  height: 100px;
  order: 3;
  flex: 0 1 100%;
 
}
```

```html
<html>
<!--...-->
 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title> Ghost </title>
  <link rel="Stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
 </head>
  
 <body>
    
  <div id="sidebar">
   Side Content
  </div>
  <div id="rightSideWrapper">
   <header> 
    Header 
   </header>
   
   <div class="ContentBox"><!--. poner en minusculas.-->
    <main> 
     Main Content 
    </main>

    <section>
     Section Content
    </section>

    <footer> 
     Footer 
    </footer>

   </div>
   
  </div>

 </body>
 

 

</html>
```

Either you can use this code.

https://jsfiddle.net/gqsaedr7/2/

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

header {
  background: black;
  padding: 15px;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
}

#wrapper {
  display: flex;
  height: 100vh;
  padding-top: 50px;
}

#navbar {
  background: pink;
  width: 20%;
  position: fixed;
  height: 100vh;
}

#content {
  background: lightblue;
  width: 100%;
  padding-left: 20%;
}
```

```html
<header>Header</header>
<div id="wrapper">
  <nav id="navbar">sidebar stuff</nav>
  <div id="content">
    <div class="class-1">
      ABC
    </div>
    <div class="class-2">
      XYZ
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This looks nice - unfortunately it won't work in my case since I don't know what the height of the header element is.

Comment: @Bluefire I sent you another code also. Please check.

Comment: Thanks! However, it still specifies the height of the header in the CSS.

Comment: @Bluefire if you dont want to use height than you have to put some content and giviethem padding. Then it will work.

Comment: @Bluefire And if i am right , then please give me feedback.

Comment: The problem is that everything below the header (i.e. the wrapper div) has `padding-top: 50` which gives it the offset to be below the header. This works if and only if the header's height is exactly 50px, but I don't know what the height will be.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204020/discussion-between-revti-shah-and-bluefire).